# Grails Db Reverse engineering generating Serializable instead of Timestamp

Tags: hibernate, grails

Hi I'm using DB reverse engineering plugin of grails and when trying to run the application after successful domain generation I get the error

**Caused by HibernateException: Wrong column type in MQ.BENEFICIARY for column creation_timestamp. Found: timestamp, expected: raw(255)**

The domain class has this field as Serializable as follows

```
class Beneficiary implements Serializable {

    String customernumber
    String nickname
    String benAccNo
    String benType
    String benStatus
    String benAccType
    String benAccCurr
    String benName
    String benAddress
    String benCity
    String benBankBic
    String benBankName
    String benBankBranch
    String benBankAddress1
    String benBankAddress2
    String benBankAddress3
    String benBankAddress4
    String benBankCity
    String benBankCountry
    String benBankCountrycode
    String clientchannel
    String creationRefno
    Serializable creationTimestamp
    String activationRefno
    Serializable activationTimestamp
    String activationCode
```

I use the following versions of Hibernate and dbreverse pluging

runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.14"

compile ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5.1'

The question is how to tell hibernate or the reverse engineering plugin to use the correct type

Answer (score 0):

This is generated code and should not be trusted, just like any generated code. You should always inspect generated code and ensure that it's correct enough to use in your application and fix it or remove it if it's not.

The plugin doesn't promise 100% correctness, only that it should save you a significant amount of time over creating domain classes by hand from database tables. In general you wouldn't run the reverse engineering script often, typically just once or a few times to create domain classes for a pre-existing database, but after that you'd manage things yourself like in any app.

I'm not sure why it's doing this; it would help if you show the column definitions for the fields that are created incorrectly. But you can easily replace `Serializable` with `Date` yourself.

Comment: Searching more online I found complaints about hibernate that it is the source of this problem. I'm not sure if db-reverse-Engineering is suing hibernate reverse engineering or not though. And in that case how can I tell hibernate in a grails application to map the types correctly on generation. I agree with you on the need to review generated code but such a trivial mapping error makes the plugin useless as it is designed to be used with massive legacy databases.